# How to reference ResourceDictionary dynamically, without path to the file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

Is there a way or workaround to reference ResourceDictionary dictionary "dynamically", for example as StaticReference or dynamic path, so in this case:

```cs
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="../../Styles/Style.xaml" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

</UserControl>
```

When I will move this user control to another folder in the solution, I would not need to update paths to the styles?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna achieve this,you can put those xaml code in App.xaml which will be the global resouces and you needn't reference it in your UserControl

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the path because it is relative to *the location of the markup of the user control*.

According to [Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **Absolute vs. Relative Pack URIs**
>
> By default, a relative pack URI is considered relative to the location of the markup or code that contains the reference. If a leading backslash is used, however, the relative pack URI reference is then considered relative to the root of the application.

Suppose `"../.."` brings you to the root of the application (where App.xaml resides), you can define the path as following

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/Style.xaml" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```